# javascipt "Cannot read property 'height' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, html

I new at javascript and I try to develop a new game and I get this message and I didn't understand why.
I glad for your help!(The error occured on the "this.top = (Math.random() * cvs.height) / 3 + 20;" line).

```
const obstablesArray = [];

class Obstable {
  constructor(cvs) {
    this.top = (Math.random() * cvs.height) / 3 + 20;
    this.bottom = (Math.random() * cvs.height) / 3 + 20;
    this.x = cvs.width;
    this.width = 20;
    this.color = "red";
    this.cvs = cvs;
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, 0, this.width, this.top);
    ctx.fillRect(
      this.x,
      this.cvs.height - this.bottom,
      this.width,
      this.bottom
    );
  }

  update(gameSpeed) {
    this.x -= gameSpeed;
    this.draw();
  }
}

export function handleObstacle(bird, ctx, frame) {
  if (frame % 50) obstablesArray.unshift(new Obstable());

  for (let i = 0; i < obstablesArray.length; i++) {
    obstablesArray[i].update(this.ctx);
  }
  if (obstablesArray.length > 20)
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      obstablesArray.pop(obstablesArray[0]);
    }
}
```

I creat the cvs on this class and send it:

```
import Bird from "/src/bird";
import { handleObstacle } from "./obstacles";

const cvs = document.getElementById("canvas1");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
cvs.width = 600;
cvs.height = 400;

let frame = 0;
let spacePress = false;
let angle = 0;
const bird = new Bird();

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);

  bird.update(cvs, spacePress, angle);
  bird.draw(ctx);
  //handleParticiles(bird, ctx);
  handleObstacle(bird, ctx, frame);
```

Comment: If you use "new obstable()" it would call the constructor which requires a parameter "cvs". Since you don't send a parameter - it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not passing `cvs` to your class constructor here:

```js
export function handleObstacle(bird, ctx, frame) {
  if (frame % 50) obstablesArray.unshift(new Obstable()); //<-- here

  ...
}
```

And cvs is of course undefined.